# Drawing random lines

Tags: gimp, effects

I would like to draw a sequence of about 100 vertical lines, with random intervals.

Is this possible with gimp?

Comment: Why the down vote? Please explain.

Comment: I downvoted because your question shows no effort at all and you should treat GD like you did with some of your quality posts on SO such as [Create an exception-safe wrapper of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392755/create-an-exception-safe-wrapper-of-a-class).  I dont know anyone here that wouldn't mind helping but effort, an example of what you have tried, and where you may be falling should be included if you want someone to put just as much time into an answer.

Comment: @Matt_2.0 as a total beginner in graphics design I don't even know where to start looking. The menus of GD software such as gimp are overwhelmingly large, and the terms in the menus are not always clear to a beginner. Next time, instead of down-voting, it could be more helpful if you write a short comment such as "try the following menu" so that I have a starting point.

Comment: Then you need to include what you have done in your question.  Someone familiar with stack I do hold at a higher level of effort and quality posts instead of just posting "show me how" with no effort or a known attempt.  Answers will never help OP's if they don't TRY or SHOW what they have tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are familiar with Inkscape, I would recommend using the `Create Tiled Clones` feature to create your vertical lines. You can then add the output to gimp.

First, create a single vertical line, then select it:

[image: Inkscape with vertical line]

Select `Edit > Create Tiled Clones...`

[image: Inkscape Edit dropdown menu]

Set the number of rows and columns as desired:

[image: Inkscape tiled clones dialog symmetry]

Set the `Shift X per Column` to be at least 100% and the `Shift X Randomize` to be greater or equal to the shift:

[image: Inkscape tiled clones dialog shift]

End result:

[image: Inkscape 100 random vertical lines]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea, select one pixel height of your canvas and use a noise filter `Filter > Noise > Hurl`.

Then if you don't want colors and just want like a mask, `Colors > Desaturate`.

Now go to the levels `Color > Levels` and adjust the arrows until you have the amount of lines and shades/colors you want.

If you want the lines to be thicker you can make more lines when adjusting the levels and then scale to the desired thickness, and height of line.

Hope this gives you an idea!

---

I have no idea what exactly you want except 100 lines width random space in between.

Here is what I did, I know it's not 100 lines but I did not scale the width:

[image: Open source rocks]

Comment: This looks interesting but I probably missed something because currently all I get is a single 1-pixel height line with random grey dots... How does this 1-pixel-height line becomes a sequence of lines?

Comment: You take the one pixel selection and use the [scale tool](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-scale.html). There are handles that can be use to scale in specific directions. The ones in middle, on the edges will scale constrained to their respective directions

Comment: [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) is free and I use it all the time. Open source rocks! (for being free :)

Comment: Oh, and you will need to zoom in to see the handles

Comment: This is so strange. I scale the selection but it remains 1-pixel high. I also tried to "float" the selection and make it a separate layer, but it still didn't work.

Comment: I also tried Filter->Distort->Iwarp, but it didn't work.

Comment: That is weird. What about creating a new file whatever width by 1px height. If you only want the lines and not the white background, create a `new layer` and choose `transparent`. generate the noise then `filter > map > tile` and mark `create a new image`. You can copy that or just add to it. Does that work?.